# Got memory pressure notification (critical) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash

I am downloading media contents from server and app crashes after certain time by giving following error:

Got memory pressure notification (critical)

Removed all object when I get warning in didReceiveMemoryWarning function but no luck.

How can I resolve this crash? Is there any way that I can restart the view controller after freeing all memory?

Comment: can you please share the crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not retaining anything in memory from all the stuff you download. There are some API calls (like imageNamed for instance) that store things into a memory cache and that will kill your app if you do too much of it too quickly.

Also crashlogs won't help. You should check memory usage in instruments to see where it's going.